# Should commercially promotional usernames be allowed?

Tags: discussion

I'm specifically referring to the user [NetConstructor.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/479/netconstuctor-com) (although this may apply to others as well).

They (he? she? it?) seem to be making a decent contribution, but judging by their username and about text on their profile, it is clear that their intention is to increase awareness of their business (even if that is secondary to their participation).

Thoughts?

Comment: ouch... northcutt :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not seeing the problem with user names being whatever the user chooses? The focus of the site is in the information, not the users. I started with Stack Overflow to do a bit of self promotion. If I was forced to change my name to something else, I probably wouldn't have bothered. If this user wants their name — whatever name they chose — to be visible, they have  to provide good content; otherwise, no one will see it anyway.

The end result is that the user has more incentive to provide good content. Who is losing out here?

Comment: I realize after my down-voted answer (really don't like having brainstorming discussions down-voted, guess I'll be more careful with my opinion on these from now on) that my concern is not company name but people using one account for (what may appear to be) multiple people. See my comments below as to why.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Definitely don't take the down-votes personally (wasn't me). They simply mean that someone does not agree with your proposal and they're NOT to be taken personally. That's one of the big reasons we removed reputation-for-votes from meta, so people would be more inclined to make suggestions and offer *real* opinions on this stuff.

Comment: Mike, I'll echo what Robert said. Don't take the downvotes personally. No rep in Meta, so the votes are just a good way of showing which ideas the community prefers. Thanks for contributing to the discussion!

Comment: Hi *@Robert Cartaino* & *@tnorthcutt*: I didn't realize that meta doesn't affect reputation. That makes me look at it differently. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is [no policy about this on the regular Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37942/policy-on-display-names), because it isn't really a problem there. Your username links to your user profile, and you were always free to link to your own site there. The commenters there who tried it say they found it had a negligible impact on site traffic.

Is NetConstructor.com answering as one person, or is the whole company using this account? I personally prefer person-bound user accounts, so if Maria is doing all the posting, maybe she could change her username to *Maria from NetConstructor*. That makes it clear NetConstructor is a company and not just a personal site.

Answer (score 0):

**@tnorthcutt** - I saw that too and am glad you brought it up.  I'd like to set a policy that people use real names if they are going to be active. The problem for me is that if *"NetConstructor"* has 5 people working there, who are we dealing with? And whose picture should we expect? I don't want an account shared by multiple people; it makes it too hard to manage.

BTW, I think we should hold people to a higher bar if they are frequent users here. If they post one question and never come back, no problem.  But NetConstructor[**has posted 10 questions already**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/479/netconstuctor-com#questions)  so he (or she) is very active which means to me we need to bring him into the community and that means knowing who he (or she) is would be beneficial to me and honestly to them.

### UPDATE

I just read [**this**](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html) by Clay Shirkey that says what I wanted to say but he says it so much better *(sorry for the length)*:

> 1.) If you were going to build a piece of social software to support large
> and long-lived groups, what would you
> design for? The first thing you would
> design for is handles the user can
> invest in.
>
> Now, I say "handles," because I don't
> want to say "identity," because
> identity has suddenly become one of
> those ideas where, when you pull on
> the little thread you want, this big
> bag of stuff comes along with it.
> Identity is such a hot-button issue
> now, but for the lightweight stuff
> required for social software, its
> really just a handle that matters.
>
> It's pretty widely understood that
> anonymity doesn't work well in group
> settings, because "who said what when"
> is the minimum requirement for having
> a conversation. What's less well
> understood is that weak pseudonymity
> doesn't work well, either. Because I
> need to associate who's saying
> something to me now with previous
> conversations.
>
> The world's best reputation management
> system is right here, in the brain.
> And actually, it's right here, in the
> back, in the emotional part of the
> brain. Almost all the work being done
> on reputation systems today is either
> trivial or useless or both, because
> reputations aren't linearizable, and
> they're not portable.
>
> ...
>
> Reputation is not necessarily portable
> from one situation to another, and
> it's not easily expressed.
>
> ...
>
> If you want a good
> reputation system, just let me
> remember who you are. And if you do me
> a favor, I'll remember it. And I won't
> store it in the front of my brain,
> I'll store it here, in the back. I'll
> just get a good feeling next time I
> get email from you; I won't even
> remember why. And if you do me a
> disservice and I get email from you,
> my temples will start to throb, and I
> won't even remember why. If you give
> users a way of remembering one
> another, reputation will happen, and
> that requires nothing more than simple
> and somewhat persistent handles.
>
> Users have to be able to identify
> themselves and there has to be a
> penalty for switching handles. The
> penalty for switching doesn't have to
> be total. But if I change my handle on
> the system, I have to lose some kind
> of reputation or some kind of context.
> This keeps the system functioning.

Comment: @Mike: Do you also have a problem with the fact that a company name is used, or only with the possibility that this is a company account? Would *Maria from NetConstructor* be an acceptable username, if this user account belonged only to Maria, and her colleague Peter used *Peter from NetConstructor*? I'm just asking this because we might otherwise confuse the two issues (multi-user accounts and company names).

Comment: I would be opposed to a "real name" policy.  I use my initials and last name as my username.  @tnorthcutt seems to do something similar.  So tracking down which are "real names" versus pseudonyms versus business names is somewhat tricky.  NetConstructor is fairly obvious ... but I used to work for a consulting agency named Parker LePla ... it *looks* like a real name, so how can re **reliably** tell the difference?

Comment: *@EAMann:* By *"real name"* I meant something that reasonably identifies you as a real and specific person; *@EAMann* and *@tnorthcutt* fully qualify as that in my book. And I don't mean something that couldn't be circumvented by a nefarious character but instead simply having a policy that people use a username that identifies them as a real and specific person *as a courtesy to the rest of the community.* For example *@techosailor* would be fine because that's what Aaron Brazell goes by everywhere online.

Comment: *@Jan Fabry*: Good question and one to ponder. Personally I don't have an issue with the company name being included; I think there is too much backlash in the WordPress community towards people actually making a living and I would hate to contribute to that. I have a problem with spam (posting solely to promote) and with anonymity and people sharing an account creates the anonymity problem. If I'm going to help someone I expect them offer me enough respect to provide an individual persona to interact with, not a corporate facade. So it's the *"multi-user"* accounts that concern me.

Comment: *@Jan Fabry*: Want to clarify the *persona* comment: I don't need nor expect to know personal information about people, i.e. their religion, their politics, their family history et. al. but I would like to know if I'm helping someone who they are compared to prior times I've helped them here or elsewhere such as WordPress.org support, WordPress group on LinkedIn, wp-hackers, etc. It makes it easier to answer when there is a history knowing skills and experience. For example I would assume I don't need to tell @hakre where to put the code I write but I would for a Wordpress noob.

Comment: This is a community site and the focus on" person" shouldn't be that overweighted. I think it's a nice gesture of a whole crowd of users from one camp is not over-run the page with multiple accounts and use one instead. That's pretty nice in the end.

Comment: Whether its a company name or a "real name" it can just as easily be used by more than one person. Regardless I think trying to enforce this policy could be problematic and a waste of time and resources. At the end of the day, the quality of the contribution is what matters. If its one user per account or 100. If the quality is there its there, if it's not it's not and if it varies it varies. In any case the accounts reputation will reflect that.

Comment: *@Ash G*: Two points, I'm suggesting a requested guidleline, not a policed rule, and as someone who has answered a *lot* of questions here it's frankly easier for me to get motivated to answer for a person with an avatar where I can see there face and hence feel like I'm "speaking" to them. I also remember if they've asked a lot of questions and I get a feel for if they are learning or not and if so I'll be happy to help but if not I don't really want to. So really me wanting a real name policy is so it's easier for me to answer questions of "real people." FWIW.

Comment: @Mike: Perhaps you should open a new discussion "Should we take extra steps to encourage individual usernames?" At least, that's how I understand your answer (and the interesting essay). With "encourage" I mean place it in the FAQ and perhaps one e-mail from a moderator, but no "penalty" if people choose not to do this. In this larger discussion your position could get lost.

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - I think you are understanding my point now. I probably should create a new discussion, but I'm stealing time away from a late client project at the moment so I'm having to limit my time here until I can make them happy.

Comment: What an interesting discussion :)  Not that it matters in regards to the root discussion but I am indeed an individual. Of course I am trying to self-promote but that should be expected on a site like this. I personally would not want to change my username BUT I do get the point being made here especially seeing that guys like Mike and hakre have been very helpful to me. For anyone else reading this... my suggestion (which I will now try to do) is end each question, answer and comment with my initials - CH, thanks guys :)... oh  -CH

Comment: @NetConstructor.com - I've thought about this a lot since posting, and it just feels wrong to use a company name here. It's self-promoting on a site where self-promotion shouldn't be the goal. Your profile page is where you should promote, not every single page where you are posting. I could use my company name to promote, but I don't because it's not my company participating here, it's me. JMTCW.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I am the company, the company is me.

Comment: @NetConstructor.com - Just for your consideration, I feel like every time I answer your question I am contributing my free time to helping you market your company, and that just doesn't feel right to me. It feels like an abuse of our help, and I don't want to feel that way even though I really do want to help. Maybe others will be able to help me see how I'm viewing it wrongly, but right now that's what my gut is saying to me.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I am honestly sorry that you feel this way. As mentioned before, I can understand where you are coming from but at least from my point of view I feel there is no real difference between my username and yours. What I mean by this is that when someone goes to your profile page you clearly advertise that you help people build software using wordpress. The only difference that I have a .com on my username. Pardon the stupidity of this next statement but I feel this is like me making an argument that one should not use ones real first/last name together but rather an alias username.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I also wanted to add that I "HIGHLY" value your opinion and your contributions to this community. I have no interest in upsetting you either. The only real point I am trying to make (or rather have you understand) is that for me the incentive is to promote myself. I feel that those users who contribute (like yourself) are the ones that make this community work and thus contributors get credit.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - One more quick thing... I know your a big advocate of trying to get people to contribute more on this forum as such... lets assume one of the managers at a big programming firm decided to open an account here with their domain name as the username and they decided to contribute company time towards answering wordpress questions. Naturally, their own intention would be to show they are experts. Now don't you feel this would be valuable to this forum and do you really feel they should not be allowed to have their website as a username?