# Is MikeSchinkel a company?

Tags: discussion, users, humor

Based on [his activity](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel), I have come to the conclusion that [MikeSchinkel](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel) must be the anonymous facade of a company. It must consist of at least:

- One developer thinking up the solutions
- One UI person creating the layouts and making the screenshots
- One copyeditor writing the answers
- One judge moderating the site
- One model posing for the profile pictures

Based on the times he is active, I think the teams are duplicated in the USA and in India, to cover more timezones. That, or they all use illicit drugs to stay awake.

To this, we must add [his other activities](http://mikeschinkel.com/), so include:

- A group of developers to serve his professional clients
- One addict to follow and fill his [Twitter stream](http://twitter.com/mikeschinkel)
- One captain for his [boat](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mikeschinkel/sets/72157594430589797/)
- One rider for his [motorcycle](http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/gettingintothezone/) (Ha, that gave you away! Nobody combines boating and biking! They're just too different!)

I think the *real* Mike behind all this must be living on a tropical island, nipping his cocktail and checking [the reputation league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/42/week/wordpress) from time to time.

So, to be fair, I suggest we ask all minions working for Mike to [create their own profile](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/should-commercially-promotional-usernames-be-allowed/131#131), so we all have a chance of getting to the top of the user list.

[Is this man a robot? http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/81df87e0d3e269d6fa6a17c6914fd656?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/81df87e0d3e269d6fa6a17c6914fd656?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)

Comment: great question :)

Comment: rofl, the only aspect I miss are clones here :)

Comment: *@Jan* - ROFLMAO! I go dark for ~36 hours trying to get some client work done, and look what I find! I almost almost want to laugh out loud but I'm a bit afraid Jan may be serious!!! OMG! (If Jan only knew one of my worst skills is to constantly struggle with delegation!!!)

Comment: Very Funny!  This should go in the Stack Exchange Hall of Fame.

Comment: one of the most valuable assets to this site... hands down :-) thanks Mike!

Comment: +1 for giving us a good laugh and a forum to thank him for his hard work.

Comment: +1+ for the most :))) thread around, thanks for the good laugh, Jan, and cheers Mr. @MikeSchinkel for being in so many places at the same time doing so many incredible stuff!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Announcing new Mikes<sup>tm</sup> for next month

To be honest, **Mike<sup>tm</sup>** is a product of my company and WordpressAnswers just our viral marketing strategy.

Our **Mikes<sup>tm</sup>** are super reliable & super green: only need to be recharged *once* a week!

I'm proud to annouce the updated version. We will release it with the beginning of Q2 in 2011. Pre-orders are taken. Be fast: the improved **Next-Gen Mike<sup>tm</sup>** is a limited edition.

[image: © from our test area]
<sub>Photo from latest production test runs.</sub>

*Every Pre-order receives a free "double speed tutorial instead of answer"-firmware update.*

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   +

If you couldn't get your hands on one of these, you maybe want to grab one of our last **Ken-Mikes<sup>tm</sup>** which is shown above by our Marketing Manager Jan Fabry - delivered with it's original pink trousers which are out of the viewport.

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   +

Don't missyour chance: Under the first hundred pre-orders we raffle a **Mike-o-Bike<sup>tm</sup>**!

Comment: Accepted because of the pink trousers. Mike, can you update the question with an uncropped photo so we can all see them?

Answer (score 13):

## Big Thanks Mike!

You  make this site worth the visits and you motivated me taking care. And I really appreceate the feedback you give, in answers, questions and comments - same for meta.

Comment: *@hakre* - Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! - I been  looking for some appreciation in the WordPress community for a while and haven't always found it in other parts of the WordPress community, but I think I've found a home. :)

Comment: Same here Mike, I really appreciate your efforts and wonder how and if you ever sleep?

Comment: I second @davemac ... your answers have had a huge impact on me. A few months ago I didn't know a thing about programming and now I'm being told that my project's (whose base I've written) are too-complex for the average freelancer. Thanks @MikeSchinkel !!!!

Answer (score 5):

This exploit is outrageous, we must remove him from the moderator team **ASAP!!!**

Comment: *@googletorp* - You are kidding, right?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Yes, you are doing a great job ;)

Answer (score 4):

I like it just the way it is `;)`. If he had to be one person, he might not get as much done `;)`.

Comment: *@Arlen Beiler* - Thanks!  (The irony is I've been mostly off the site for a few days because of client work!)