# How to promote this site to other WordPress developers?

Tags: wordpress.org

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we better promote this site and attract more users?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-can-we-better-promote-this-site-and-attract-more-users)

I found this few days ago and even if I love stackoverflow.com, I was skeptic about its possible success but I tried asking two questions and I was well surprised.

There are many other forums than the one on wordpress.org site, most of them hosted by other plugins developers. Should we encourage people to migrate?

Now the question **what have you done to increase the number of users?**

Comment: This question belongs on Meta and has already been asked there: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-can-we-better-promote-this-site-and-attract-more-users