# What type of machine is Toscho?

Tags: discussion, humor

I think the poster in these comments might be on to something ( https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75359/how-to-make-recent-posts-shortcode-carousel-posts-with-navigation ) when he alluded to the user [Toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) being a

> funny robot imitating an actual person

I was surprised to further learn it says so right on his profile

> "Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!"

Further evidence can be found via this User badge which only a robot can earn: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/74/archaeologist

- Is it possible he is an electro-mechanical machine ?
- If he is just  a background process, what language is he written in ?
- How do I get one ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's just new model of [Mike Schinkel](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/is-mikeschinkel-a-company). Standard issue for every stack. Rest of the mods just keep illusion of democracy up.

Comment: Oh so he assassinated @mikeschinkel with an improved mimetic poly-alloy frame, I get it.

Answer (score 8):

The eye that **all sees**.

[image: toscho in the sky with d's]

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely impossible that he may be Zion, or the creator of all and thus the observer of everything. You feel him all around you all the time - everywhere. Although he is not perfect, he does malfunction in the blink of a moment and you feel it: You know the sudden scare that you get when you lean too far back on your chair, that is when Toscho deletes one of its processors through task manager.

Answer (score 0):

One man show, but never sleep and always on WPSE to share his knowhow; crazy ;)

"Groundhog Day": like [Mike](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/is-mikeschinkel-a-company)